# How to activate and run JavaScript in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, javascript

I'm trying to run simple script in *AppleScript Editor* on OS X 10.9.5, but using JavaScript, e.g.:

```
var SE = new Application("System Events");
SE.processes.windows.name()
```

However my dropdown only shows *AppleScript*.

How do I activate JavaScript if it isn't appearing on the list? It is also not in *Preferences/General*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. [JavaScript for Automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/Introduction.html) was only introduced in OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

AppleScript Editor.app was also renamed to Script Editor.app due to it now not only being for AppleScript.